# Synchronous findOne with sort() in mongoose mongdb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to find document with the latest "sorting_index" field.
I try so:

```
var sorting_index = -1;
this.findOne().sort({'sorting_index': -1}).exec(function(err, doc) {   
    if (err) return;
    sorting_index = doc['sorting_index']; // sorting_index == 10      
});                         
console.log(sorting_index); // sorting_index == -1
```

The problem is that the callback is asynchronous. How to do it synchronically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer - you can't.

If you want your code to be synchronous you should consider using some other tool instead of `node.js`.

All I/O operations in node.js are asynchronous, so if you want to work with node.js then you should learn how to deal with async code:

```
this.findOne().sort({sorting_index: -1}).exec(function(err, doc) {   
    if (err) throw err;
    var sorting_index = doc['sorting_index'];
    console.log(sorting_index); // sorting_index == 10
});
```

There is also a lot of helpful tools to simplify your async code: async.js, promises, ES6 generators (node.js 11.x), etc.

Answer (score 2):

## Synchronous-Like Syntax Example

Try bumping up your version using `nvm` to Node 8+ or higher as its pretty great. Go to latest Node LTS while you are at it.

Try something like so to make your life easier making sure to mark the function you are using as `async` **(assuming you are on a class)** and using `await` where you need to get the actual thing that normally is used with Promise chaining.

```
async findSortIndex() {
  try {
    const doc = await this.findOne().sort({ sorting_index: -1 })
    console.log(doc.sorting_index)
  } catch(err) {
    return Promise.reject(err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be cautious with using await with chained methods like that.

I had a piece of code that went something like

```
const DbModelInstances = await DbModelInstance.find().sort("-dateAdded");
```

Something went wrong and my unit tests got messed up due to synchrinicity issues. I removed the sort statement and it worked fine. 
I've only just spotted it this morning, so I don't have a thorough explanation yet, but as I ran into this post I thought I'd mention it just in case someone else has had the same problem.